# Importing a module in Python

Tags: python, module

I'm going through the Python tutorial, and I got to the section on modules.

I created a fibo.py file in Users/Me/code/Python   (s

Now I'm back in the interpreter and I can't seem to import the module, because I don't understand how to import a relative (or absolute) path.

I'm also thoroughly confused by how and if to modify PYTHONPATH and/or sys.path.

All the other 'import module' questions on here seem to be

Comment: There's lots of truncated text in this question.  You should be explicit about what all the paths involved are.

Comment: Agreed. Just a reminder it is considered best practice to either put your global modules in python itself (the site-packages folder) or to just put the module in the same directory as the python program you are currently running.

Comment: "All the other 'import module' questions on here seem to be" incomplete?  unfinished?  broken?

Comment: Google seems to lead here. I recommend people check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/5289570) as of today.

Answer (score 5):

```
import sys

sys.path.append('your/dir')

import yourmod
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have paths for imports is when these are submodules or subpackages of some packge. This is explained in the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

`PYTHONPATH` defines in which directories, other than the current working directory, the interpreter looks for an import. So, suppose you have your module at `/Users/Code/Me/Python/fibo.py`. If you set `PYTHONPATH` to `/Users/Code/Me/Python/`, you will be able to import your module like this:

```
import fibo
```

Comment: It also looks in the current directory

Comment: @Falmarri: That is why I wrote *other than the current working directory*.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that =\

Answer (score 0):

If you're just testing, you can do

```
import os
os.chdir(<directory-with-your-module>)
import fibo
```

Answer (score 0):

Before importing any user defined module,specify the path to the directory containg that module
sys.path.append("path to your directory")