# Relative imports for the billionth time

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path, python-packaging, relative-import

I've been here:

- *[PEP 328 – Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)*
- *[Modules, Packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)*
- [Python packages: relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059002/python-packages-relative-imports)
- [Python relative import example code does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123062/python-relative-import-example-code-does-not-work)
- [Relative imports in Python 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports)
- [Relative imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python)
- [Python: Disabling relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233931/python-disabling-relative-import)

and plenty of URLs that I did not copy, some on SO, some on other sites, back when I thought I'd have the solution quickly.

The forever-recurring question is this: how do I solve this "Attempted relative import in non-package" message?

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I built an exact replica of the package on pep-0328:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        moduleZ.py
    moduleA.py
```

The imports were done from the console.

I did make functions named spam and eggs in their appropriate modules.  Naturally, it didn't work.  The answer is apparently in the 4th URL I listed, but it's all alumni to me. There was this response on one of the URLs I visited:

> Relative imports use a module's name attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to 'main') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

The above response looks promising, but it's all hieroglyphs to me. How do I make Python not return to me "Attempted relative import in non-package"? It has an answer that involves `-m`, supposedly.

Why does Python give that error message? What does by "non-package" mean? Why and how do you define a 'package'?

Comment: See my answer.  You still haven't fully clarified what you're doing, but if you're trying to do `from .something import something` in the interactive interpreter, that won't work.  Relative imports can only be used within modules, not interactively.

Comment: Related question: [Python3 correct way to import relative or absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28400690/2142994)

Comment: @CodeJockey see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145047/cannot-get-import-to-work-with-subpackages for context.

Comment: In addition, relative imports don't work in the same way in PowerShell as Windows Command Prompt. Use Command Prompt to run scripts with relative imports.

Comment: There's more to this than meets the eye. Same project, same setup on my team. Python 3.8 anaconda one one; relative imports work. Python 3.9 on mine; doesn't work. I've been on several projects now where relative imports worked on one person's machine but not the other. Running same command from the same directory.

Comment: See this workaround for a relative local import of a Python file from another project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070953/python-import-package-from-different-project/75426574#75426574

Comment: Re *"There was this response on one of the URLs I visited"*: Where is it from?

Comment: OK, it is probably from *[Guido’s Decision](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)*: *"Relative Imports and \_\_name\_\_. Relative imports use a module’s \_\_name\_\_ attribute to determine that module’s position..."*

Answer (score 2266, accepted):

**Script vs. Module**

Here's an explanation.  The short version is that there is a big difference between directly running a Python file, and importing that file from somewhere else.  **Just knowing what directory a file is in does not determine what package Python thinks it is in.**  That depends, additionally, on how you load the file into Python (by running or by importing).

There are two ways to load a Python file: as the top-level script, or as a
module.  A file is loaded as the top-level script if you execute it directly, for instance by typing `python myfile.py` on the command line.  It is loaded as a module when an `import` statement is encountered inside some other file.  There can only be one top-level script at a time; the top-level script is the Python file you ran to start things off.

**Naming**

When a file is loaded, it is given a name (which is stored in its `__name__` attribute).  If it was loaded as the top-level script, its name is `__main__`.  If it was loaded as a module, its name is the filename, preceded by the names of any packages/subpackages of which it is a part, separated by dots.

So for instance in your example:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
    moduleA.py
```

if you imported `moduleX` (note: *imported*, not directly executed), its name would be `package.subpackage1.moduleX`.  If you imported `moduleA`, its name would be `package.moduleA`.  However, if you *directly run* `moduleX` from the command line, its name will instead be `__main__`, and if you directly run `moduleA` from the command line, its name will be `__main__`.  When a module is run as the top-level script, it loses its normal name and its name is instead `__main__`.

**Accessing a module NOT through its containing package**

There is an additional wrinkle: the module's name depends on whether it was imported "directly" from the directory it is in or imported via a package.  This only makes a difference if you run Python in a directory, and try to import a file in that same directory (or a subdirectory of it).  For instance, if you start the Python interpreter in the directory `package/subpackage1` and then do `import moduleX`, the name of `moduleX` will just be `moduleX`, and not `package.subpackage1.moduleX`.  This is because Python adds the current directory to its search path when the interpreter is entered interactively; if it finds the to-be-imported module in the current directory, it will not know that that directory is part of a package, and the package information will not become part of the module's name.

A special case is if you run the interpreter interactively (e.g., just type `python` and start entering Python code on the fly).  In this case, the name of that interactive session is `__main__`.

Now here is the crucial thing for your error message: **if a module's name has no dots, it is not considered to be part of a package**.  It doesn't matter where the file actually is on disk.  All that matters is what its name is, and its name depends on how you loaded it.

Now look at the quote you included in your question:

> Relative imports use a module's name attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to 'main') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top-level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

**Relative imports...**

Relative imports use the module's *name* to determine where it is in a package.  When you use a relative import like `from .. import foo`, the dots indicate to step up some number of levels in the package hierarchy.  For instance, if your current module's name is `package.subpackage1.moduleX`, then `..moduleA` would mean `package.moduleA`.  For a `from .. import` to work, the module's name must have at least as many dots as there are in the `import` statement.

**... are only relative in a package**

However, if your module's name is `__main__`, it is not considered to be in a package.  Its name has no dots, and therefore you cannot use `from .. import` statements inside it.  If you try to do so, you will get the "relative-import in non-package" error.

**Scripts can't import relative**

What you probably did is you tried to run `moduleX` or the like from the command line.  When you did this, its name was set to `__main__`, which means that relative imports within it will fail, because its name does not reveal that it is in a package. Note that this will also happen if you run Python from the same directory where a module is, and then try to import that module, because, as described above, Python will find the module in the current directory "too early" without realizing it is part of a package.

Also remember that when you run the interactive interpreter, the "name" of that interactive session is always `__main__`.  Thus **you cannot do relative imports directly from an interactive session**.  Relative imports are only for use within module files.

**Two solutions:**

1. If you really do want to run `moduleX` directly, but you still want it to be considered part of a package, you can do `python -m package.subpackage1.moduleX`.  The `-m` tells Python to load it as a module, not as the top-level script.
2. Or perhaps you don't actually want to *run* `moduleX`, you just want to run some other script, say `myfile.py`, that *uses* functions inside `moduleX`.  If that is the case, put `myfile.py` *somewhere else* – *not* inside the `package` directory – and run it.  If inside `myfile.py` you do things like `from package.moduleA import spam`, it will work fine.

**Notes**

- For either of these solutions, the package directory (`package` in your example) must be accessible from the Python module search path (`sys.path`).  If it is not, you will not be able to use anything in the package reliably at all.
- Since Python 2.6, the module's "name" for package-resolution purposes is determined not just by its `__name__` attributes but also by the `__package__` attribute.  That's why I'm avoiding using the explicit symbol `__name__` to refer to the module's "name".  Since Python 2.6 a module's "name" is effectively `__package__ + '.' + __name__`, or just `__name__` if `__package__` is `None`.)

Comment: Can you explain `__package__` more?  Also, let's say that __init__.py in the 'package' folder is the top-level script I want to execute from.  How do I set up the relative imports in ModuleX and in __init__.py so that they work?  Could you provide a working example?

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: The example you have is working, if you use it in the right way.  If you want to run that `__init__.py`, you could do `python -m package.__init__`.  However, that is probably a bad idea, as it's not what `__init__.py` is for, and most packages will behave strangely or do nothing if you do that.  If you provide a `__main__.py` in `package`, you could execute that with `python -m package`.  See [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for more info about `__package__` and `__main__.py`.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: I agree that the behavior is somewhat confusing.  It is not changed in Python 3.  However, it is consistent with Python's overall module/package philosophy, which is that the actual directory structure is less important than Python's view of it via `sys.path`, etc.  I myself often wish that the Python module system were jst a transparent reflection of the directory tree, but it isn't.

Comment: The link to PEP 366 is a life-saver because it includes an ad hoc solution to this problem.  However, I'm still unsure how this would be set up if you try and set it up normally from __main__... and it seems like Python is looking at __init__.py when it can't find a reference (I figured this out by typing `ModuleY` instead of `moduleY`).  I thought Python was supposed to be explicit, not secretive like that.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: PEP 366 shows how that works.  Inside a file, you can do `__package__ = 'package.subpackage1'` or the like.  Then *that file only* will *always* be considered part of that package even if run directly.  If you have other questions about `__package__` you might want to ask a separate question as we're getting off the issue of your original question here.

Comment: I've translated this answer into 中文 [here](http://www.laike9m.com/blog/pythonxiang-dui-dao-ru-ji-zhi-xiang-jie,60/).

Comment: My understanding is that this paragraph is incomplete : "When a file is loaded, it is given a name (which is stored in its `__name__` attribute). If it was loaded as the top-level script, its name is `__main__`. If it was loaded as a module," add "via `import module`, "its name is the filename," add "minus .py/.pyc", " preceded by the names of any packages/subpackages of which it is a part, separated by dots." add "If was loaded as a module via the `-m package.module` syntax, then its name is also `__main__`.

Comment: Also clarify, "When you use a relative import like `from .. import foo`, the dots indicate to step up some number of levels in the package hierarchy. For instance, if your current module's name is `package.subpackage1.moduleX`, then `..moduleA would mean package.moduleA`. For a `from .. import` to work, the module's name must have at least as many dots as there are in the import statement." Add that each module at each level above needs to be imported. Simply saying this won't work: `if __name__ == '__main__': __package__ = 'package.subpackage1'; '__name__' = 'package.subpackage1.moduleA'`

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/ -- "Note that this boilerplate is sufficient only if the top level package is already accessible via sys.path . Additional code that manipulates sys.path would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable." -- this is the most disturbing bit to me since this "additional code" is actually quite long and can't be stored elsewhere in package to run easily.

Comment: I keep coming back to this post despite being a Python veteran. The main message for me is: Either fiddle around with `sys.path` and `__package__` (which is rather ugly, see the other answers) or simply create a "main script" `main.py` in the root directory of your project and put all modules to be imported in subdirectories. `main.py` can then access all modules directly through their package names (= the names of the respective folders they're in).

Comment: "Python adds the current directory to its search path" confused me because I thought it mean the directory`python` is invoked from. To be exact, Python adds the *directory containing the top-level script* to its search path. Furthermore, if the top-level script is a symlink, the current directory of the *symlink's target* is what gets added to its search path.

Comment: As one who develops code using pycharm and jupyter, and then sometimes uses it with python rq as a "task" I find it extremely frustrating to keep getting ImportErrors, especially when there's no good reason or explanation as to why relative imports aren't allowed - just a vague reference to __name__ being __main__ as if that explains everything.  If I say from .mylib import Foo, I don't really care if I'm in the __main__ (script) context -- I just want my class imported.  I think the PEP police ought to do something :-)  (ok flame suit on, check.)

Comment: This answer is currently off on a few important details regarding `__name__` and `sys.path`. Specifically, with `python -m pkg.mod`, `__name__` is set to `__main__`, not `pkg.mod`; relative imports are resolved using [`__package__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/#proposed-change) rather than `__name__` in this case. Also, Python adds the script's directory rather than the current directory to `sys.path` when running `python path/to/script.py`; it adds the current directory to `sys.path` when running most other ways, including `python -m pkg.mod`.

Comment: Finally understand after hours of reading... Worth noting that code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` will still run when using -m. See the comment from @user2357112

Comment: Hi. But isn't a module still also loaded as a script with python -m? I understood that only time a module is executed as one is when it's imported .. . That's implied in here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: In your solutions, can you update so that we know from where you are running the code? (Working directory)

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Python docs should mention this - 'relative imports are not meant for top-level scripts'. This is enough for a beginner to ask and understand why it is so, or ignore the feature altogether.

Comment: @BrenBarn thanks for this amazing answer. One statement in your answer that still confuses me after reading it several times: "For a from .. import to work, the module's name must have at least as many dots as there are in the import statement." 
If a module's `__name__` is package.foo and it has `from .. import bar`, then interpreter can tell foo must be located at a directory namely package which is under one of the top-level directories (i.e. sys.path). ".." basically tell the interpreter to step out the package directory, move one level top and look for bar? I tried that but not works...

Comment: There is another alternative which allows you to use absolute imports in any project file without messing with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`. Create a minimal setup.py file and install your package locally using the editable flag like `python -m pip install -e .`. This article explains it https://realpython.com/python-import/#create-and-install-a-local-package

Comment: A feature is broken if you have to spend an hour reading this, and if you have to google it time after time, and still only the gurus get it. The python designers dropped the ball on this one, and it should just work, the first time, like any other programming language.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Had the same problem so many times and never understood why. Now everything is so clear. Should be part of "Python Primer"

Comment: Thanks. Not by any strech I could figure out how to create a package other than name it `__main__.py` and `from .submodule  import module`  to run it with `python -m package` when installed. In the project folder i now run `python -m package.__main__` to test it localy. If there is a better solution, please share.

Comment: The most important part:  "scripts can't import relative"

Comment: If you're having this issue while running unit tests, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure - this unblocked me.

Comment: "Note that this will also happen if you run Python from the same directory where a module is, and then try to import that module, because, as described above, Python will find the module in the current directory "too early" without realizing it is part of a package."     

Huh? I don't have any problems running Python from the same directory in which a module is in and then import the module.

Comment: Because your solution is the more popular, and it doesn't works for a lot of people finding your answer, you should add adding a third parent folder, that holds both siblings, and solves the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114877/9404261

Comment: People should not need to know any of this to get a simple import to work.

Answer (score 104):

This is really a problem within python. **The origin of confusion is that people mistakenly take the relative import as path relative which is not.**

For example when you write in *faa.py*:

```
from .. import foo
```

This has a meaning only if *faa.py* was *identified and loaded* by python, during execution, as a part of a package. In that case, the **module's name**
for *faa.py* would be for example *some_packagename.faa*. If the file was loaded just because it is in the current directory, when python is run, then its name would not refer to any package and eventually relative import would fail.

A simple solution to refer modules in the current directory, is to use this:

```
if __package__ is None or __package__ == '':
    # uses current directory visibility
    import foo
else:
    # uses current package visibility
    from . import foo
```

Comment: The correct solution is  `from __future__ import absolute_import` and force the user to use your code correctly... so that you can always do `from . import foo`

Comment: If you use IDE (and the only IDE for python is Pycharm), it manages imports by itself, and you have to manually copy them every time. Not good solution. And if `foo` ist an installed package, it will be used instead of your local file.

Comment: @SmitJohnth Another IDE for Python is Spyder. I bet there are more.

Comment: @Joooeey no, it's "IDE". The only IDE without quotes I know is Pycharm.

Answer (score 56):

There are too many long answers in a foreign language. So, I'll try to make it short.

If you write `from . import module`, opposite to what you think, `module` will not be imported from current directory, but from the top level of your package! If you run *.py* file as a script, it simply doesn't know where the top level is and thus refuses to work.

If you start it like this `py -m package.module` from the directory above `package`, then Python knows where the top level is. That's very similar to Java: `java -cp bin_directory package.class`

Comment: This is in @BrenBarn's answer, but it's the TL;DR of it. OP and anyone else looking for answers, this is it. Took me forever to find this elsewhere.

Comment: What is even more confusing is that when you install a package, absolute imports don't work for me. i need to use from `.submodule import module`. When i use `import submodule.module`  or `from submodule import module`, it can't be found, even when the folder is right in the package folder.

Comment: @LeviLesches I think we need TL;DRs. English is not my native language, and I don't have time to read walls of text which can be lossless compressed to a paragraph. Are people doing this paid for it? Is it chinese answers, like chinese code when they were paid for code lines?

Comment: Part of this answer is wrong. `from . import module` doesn't import from "the top level of the package", it imports from *the same package* as the module the import statement is written in, which may be some deep subpackage in a complicated package hierarchy.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm sure I answered you but my answer disappeared.

Answer (score 24):

So after carping about this along with many others, I came across a note posted by [Dorian B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5420054/dorian-b) in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286210/is-there-a-way-to-access-parent-modules-in-python) that solved the specific problem I was having where I would develop modules and classes for use with a web service, but I also want to be able to test them as I'm coding, using the debugger facilities in PyCharm. To run tests in a self-contained class, I would include the following at the end of my class file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # run test code here...
```

but if I wanted to import other classes or modules in the same folder, I would then have to change all my import statements from relative notation to local references (i.e. remove the dot (.))  But after reading Dorian's suggestion, I tried his 'one-liner' and it worked!  I can now test in PyCharm and leave my test code in place when I use the class in another class under test, or when I use it in my web service!

```
# import any site-lib modules first, then...
import sys
parent_module = sys.modules['.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1]) or '__main__']
if __name__ == '__main__' or parent_module.__name__ == '__main__':
    from codex import Codex # these are in same folder as module under test!
    from dblogger import DbLogger
else:
    from .codex import Codex
    from .dblogger import DbLogger
```

The if statement checks to see if we're running this module as **main** or if it's being used in another module that's being tested as **main**.  Perhaps this is obvious, but I offer this note here in case anyone else frustrated by the relative import issues above can make use of it.

Comment: I have a similar issue -- tools that have to be packaged into the same folder to work as an add-on to another larger program. The main add-on interfaces with the larger program and works only when that larger program is running. For testing, I want to run the smaller utilities and let them call each other. It's a nightmare. I've started just using chained ``try``/``except ImportError`` blocks and adding every possible way of importing something in there. It works, it's short, but is so incredibly unpythonic it hurts every time.

Comment: This is my exact use case, testing/debugging within PyCharm. The solution, for PyCharm users, is to setup one or more 'Source Roots'. From the PyCharm docs
 
"PyCharm uses the source roots as the starting point for resolving imports."

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html

Comment: You said you use Pycharm. It manages imports by itself, and you have to manually copy them every time. Not good solution.

Comment: "Perhaps this is obvious" .. umm *that* code is obvious?    I'm going to stash it away somewhere in any case - given I live and die by JetBrains tools..

Answer (score 17):

Here is one solution that I would not recommend, but might be useful in some situations where modules were simply not generated:

```
import os
import sys
parent_dir_name = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(parent_dir_name + "/your_dir")
import your_script
your_script.a_function()
```

Comment: Also check the answer of Lars who created a clean version of this answer that you can just copy/paste as boilerplate into all of your modules.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a general recipe, modified to fit as an example, that I am using right now for dealing with Python libraries written as packages, that contain interdependent files, where I want to be able to test parts of them piecemeal.  Let's call this `lib.foo` and say that it needs access to `lib.fileA` for functions `f1` and `f2`, and `lib.fileB` for class `Class3`.

I have included a few `print` calls to help illustrate how this works.  In practice you would want to remove them (and maybe also the `from __future__ import print_function` line).

This particular example is too simple to show when we really need to insert an entry into `sys.path`.  (See [Lars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455936/1256452) for a case where we *do* need it, when we have two or more levels of package directories, and then we use `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`—but it doesn't really *hurt* here either.)  It's also safe enough to do this without the `if _i in sys.path` test.  However, if each imported file inserts the same path—for instance, if both `fileA` and `fileB` want to import utilities from the package—this clutters up `sys.path` with the same path many times, so it's nice to have the `if _i not in sys.path` in the boilerplate.

```
from __future__ import print_function # only when showing how this works

if __package__:
    print('Package named {!r}; __name__ is {!r}'.format(__package__, __name__))
    from .fileA import f1, f2
    from .fileB import Class3
else:
    print('Not a package; __name__ is {!r}'.format(__name__))
    # these next steps should be used only with care and if needed
    # (remove the sys.path manipulation for simple cases!)
    import os, sys
    _i = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    if _i not in sys.path:
        print('inserting {!r} into sys.path'.format(_i))
        sys.path.insert(0, _i)
    else:
        print('{!r} is already in sys.path'.format(_i))
    del _i # clean up global name space

    from fileA import f1, f2
    from fileB import Class3

... all the code as usual ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest, sys
    ret = doctest.testmod()
    sys.exit(0 if ret.failed == 0 else 1)
```

The idea here is this (and note that these all function the same across Python 2.7 and Python 3.x):

1. If run as `import lib` or `from lib import foo` as a regular package import from ordinary code, `__package` is `lib` and `__name__` is `lib.foo`.  We take the first code path, importing from `.fileA`, etc.
2. If run as `python lib/foo.py`, `__package__` will be None and `__name__` will be `__main__`.

   We take the second code path.  The `lib` directory will already be in `sys.path` so there is no need to add it.  We import from `fileA`, etc.
3. If run within the `lib` directory as `python foo.py`, the behavior is the same as for case 2.
4. If run within the `lib` directory as `python -m foo`, the behavior is similar to cases 2 and 3.  However, the path to the `lib` directory is not in `sys.path`, so we add it before importing.  The same applies if we run Python and then `import foo`.

   (Since `.` *is* in `sys.path`, we don't really need to add the absolute version of the path here.  This is where a deeper package nesting structure, where we want to do `from ..otherlib.fileC import ...`, makes a difference.  If you're not doing this, you can omit all the `sys.path` manipulation entirely.)

#### Notes

There is still a quirk.  If you run this whole thing from outside:

```
python2 lib.foo
```

or:

```
python3 lib.foo
```

the behavior depends on the contents of `lib/__init__.py`.  If that exists and *is empty*, all is well:

```
Package named 'lib'; __name__ is '__main__'
```

But if `lib/__init__.py` *itself* imports `routine` so that it can export `routine.name` directly as `lib.name`, you get:

```
python2 lib.foo
```

Output:

```
Package named 'lib'; __name__ is 'lib.foo'
Package named 'lib'; __name__ is '__main__'
```

That is, the module gets imported twice, once via the package and then again as `__main__` so that it runs your `main` code.  Python 3.6 and later warn about this:

```
python3 lib.routine
```

Output:

```
Package named 'lib'; __name__ is 'lib.foo'
[...]/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'lib.foo' found in sys.modules
after import of package 'lib', but prior to execution of 'lib.foo';
this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
Package named 'lib'; __name__ is '__main__'
```

The *warning* is new, but the warned-about behavior is not.  It is part of what some call [the double import trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap).  (For additional details see [issue 27487](https://bugs.python.org/issue27487).)  Nick Coghlan says:

> This next trap exists in all current versions of Python, including 3.3, and can be summed up in the following general guideline: "Never add a package directory, or any directory inside a package, directly to the Python path".

Note that while we violate that rule here, we do it *only* when the file being loaded is *not* being loaded as part of a package, and our modification is specifically designed to allow us to access other files in that package.  (And, as I noted, we probably shouldn't do this at all for single level packages.)  If we wanted to be extra-clean, we might rewrite this as, e.g.:

```
    import os, sys
    _i = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    if _i not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, _i)
    else:
        _i = None

    from sub.fileA import f1, f2
    from sub.fileB import Class3

    if _i:
        sys.path.remove(_i)
    del _i
```

That is, we modify `sys.path` long enough to achieve our imports, then put it back the way it was (deleting one copy of `_i` if and only if we added one copy of `_i`).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where I didn't want to change the Python module search path and needed to load a module relatively *from a script* (in spite of *"scripts can't import relative with all"* as [BrenBarn explained nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/14132912#14132912)).

So I used the following hack. Unfortunately, it relies on the `imp` module that
became deprecated since version 3.4 to be dropped in favour of `importlib`.
(Is this possible with `importlib`, too? I don't know.) Still, the hack works for now.

Example for accessing members of `moduleX` in `subpackage1` from a script residing in the `subpackage2` folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import inspect
import imp
import os

def get_script_dir(follow_symlinks=True):
    """
    Return directory of code defining this very function.
    Should work from a module as well as from a script.
    """
    script_path = inspect.getabsfile(get_script_dir)
    if follow_symlinks:
        script_path = os.path.realpath(script_path)
    return os.path.dirname(script_path)

# loading the module (hack, relying on deprecated imp-module)
PARENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(get_script_dir())
(x_file, x_path, x_desc) = imp.find_module('moduleX', [PARENT_PATH+'/'+'subpackage1'])
module_x = imp.load_module('subpackage1.moduleX', x_file, x_path, x_desc)

# importing a function and a value
function = module_x.my_function
VALUE = module_x.MY_CONST
```

A cleaner approach seems to be to modify the sys.path used for loading modules as [mentioned by Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time/37934474#37934474).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    # __file__ should be defined in this case
    PARENT_DIR = path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))
   sys.path.append(PARENT_DIR)
from subpackage1.moduleX import *
```

Comment: That looks better... too bad it still requires you to embed the name of the parent directory in the file... maybe that can be improved with importlib. Maybe importlib can even be monkeypatched to make relative import "just work" for simple use cases. I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.14 though. Would something like this still work ?

Comment: I just tested both approaches on python 2.7.10 and they worked fine for me. If fact, you do not have the problem of a deprecated imp module in 2.7, so all the better.

Comment: Came back to this after years and just wanted to mention, that this answer, that last code snippet with the cleaner version, I am using in all my code for quite some time now. It is messy and you have this ugly boiler plate, but it is working like I would expect it to work in the first place. Currently I am using Python 3.11 and still this is not part of the normal behavior. Very sad. But this is really helping. Thank you @Lars.

Answer (score 6):

@BrenBarn's answer says it all, but if you're like me it might take a while to understand.  Here's my case and how @BrenBarn's answer applies to it, perhaps it will help you.

**The case**

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleX.py
    moduleA.py
```

Using our familiar example, and add to it that moduleX.py has a relative import to ..moduleA.  Given that I tried writing a test script in the subpackage1 directory that imported moduleX, but then got the dreaded error described by the OP.

**Solution**

Move test script to the same level as package and import package.subpackage1.moduleX

**Explanation**

As explained, relative imports are made relative to the current name.  When my test script imports moduleX from the same directory, then module name inside moduleX is moduleX.  When it encounters a relative import the interpreter can't back up the package hierarchy because it's already at the top

When I import moduleX from above, then name inside moduleX is package.subpackage1.moduleX and the relative import can be found

Comment: Hoping you can guide me on this. In the following link, if you go to Case 3, it says solution 1 is not possible. Please can you check this and let me know. It will help me immensely. https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.htm

Comment: @variable there's a typo in the link and I'm not allowed to edit. Looked at case 3 and didn't follow exactly what you're getting at. When I tried that example in python 2 there were no issues which makes me think I missed something. Maybe you should post a new question but need to provide a clearer example. Case 4 touches on what I'm talking about in my answer here: you can't go up a directory for relative import UNLESS the interpreter starts in a parent directory

Comment: Thanks I'm referring to python 3 and here the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577767/python-m-switch-to-run-module-inside-package

Comment: @BradDre typo fixed: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Answer (score 4):

Following up on what Lars has suggested I've wrapped this approach in an experimental, new import library: [ultraimport](https://github.com/ronny-rentner/ultraimport)

It gives the programmer more control over imports and it allows file system based imports. Therefore, you can do relative imports from scripts. Parent package not necessary. ultraimports will always work, no matter how you run your code or what is your current working directory because ultraimport makes imports unambiguous. You don't need to change sys.path and also you don't need a try/except block to sometimes do relative imports and sometimes absolute.

You would then write in somefile.py something like:

```
import ultraimport
foo = ultraimport('__dir__/foo.py')
```

__dir__ is the directory of somefile.py, the caller of ultraimport(). foo.py would live in the same directory as somefile.py.

One caveat when importing scripts like this is if they contain further relative imports. ultraimport has a builtin preprocessor to rewrite subsequent relative imports to ultraimports so they continue to work. Though, this is currently somewhat limited as original Python imports are ambiguous and there's only so much you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dead simple solution in case you don't want to do any of these:

- add `__init__.py` files
- run with `python -m mymodule`
- edit  `__package__`
- add `if` check in `__main__`
- edit `sys.path` by hand
- edit `PYTHONPATH`
- restructure the project

### pip install importmonkey

This is a robust wrapper around sys.path hacks to keep everything simple and neat.

[[github](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey)] [[pip](https://pypi.org/project/importmonkey/)] [[docs](https://github.com/hirsimaki-markus/importmonkey/blob/b57ffc7412eda20f8820e30bf27c2ccc309d389d/src/importmonkey/__init__.py#L25C49-L25C49)]

```
├─ src
│   └─ project
│       └─ mymodule.py
└─ test
    └─ test.py
```

```py
# In test.py

from importmonkey import add_path
add_path("../src/project")  # relative to current __file__
import mymodule

# add as many paths as needed, absolute or relative
# unix path conventions work so you can use '..' and '.'
# add_path validates the paths and returns added path as string
```

The module does not need to have `__init__.py` associated with it for this to work.

Disclosure of affiliation: I made importmonkey.

Comment: "if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer (or any other contribution to the site), you must disclose your affiliation in your post" https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @SolomonUcko thank you for the reminder. I will try to remember that. In this case it is my own creation.

Answer (score 2):

`__name__` changes depending on whether the code in question is run in the global namespace or as part of an imported module.

If the code is not running in the global space, `__name__` will be the name of the module. If it is running in global namespace -- for example, if you type it into a console, or run the module as a script using `python.exe yourscriptnamehere.py` then `__name__` becomes `"__main__"`.

You'll see a lot of python code with  `if __name__ == '__main__'` is used to test whether the code is being run from the global namespace – that allows you to have a module that doubles as a script.

Did you try to do these imports from the console?

Comment: Ah, so you mention -m.  That makes your module execute as a script - if you stick an if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_' in there you should see that it is '\_\_main\_\_' because of the -m.

Try just importing your module into another module so it is not the top level... that should allow you to do the relative import

Comment: I tried to do these imports from the console, with the active file being the correct module.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: What do you mean the "active file"?

Comment: I use Pyscripter.  I was in moduleX.py when I ran these imports: from .moduleY import spam *and* from . import ModuleY.

Answer (score 1):

> Relative imports use a module's name attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to 'main') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

I wrote [a small Python package](https://pypi.org/project/import-anywhere/) to [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) that might help viewers of this question. The package acts as workaround if one wishes to be able to run Python files containing imports containing upper level packages from within a package / project without being directly in the importing file's directory.

Answer (score 0):

For the poor souls like me which cannot make anything of this works, here is the solution posted by [FEMista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114877/9404261)

Add an intermediate parent folder, to act as common branch for both siblings:

```
package/    
    __init__.py
    SUBPACKAGES/
        __init__.py
        subpackage1/
            __init__.py
            moduleX.py
            moduleY.py
        subpackage2/
            __init__.py
            moduleZ.py
        moduleA.py
```

Remember to add the folder `SUBPACKAGES` to the `import` paths.

Comment: How does this help? All you did was replace ```package``` with ```SUBPACKAGES```.

Answer (score -2):

In most cases when I see the `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` and pull my hair out, the solution is as follows:

You need to **step one level higher** in the file hierarchy!

```py
#dir/package/module1/foo.py

#dir/package/module2/bar.py
from ..module1 import foo
```

Importing `bar.py` when interpreter is started in `dir/package/` will result in error despite the import process never going beyond your current directory.

Importing `bar.py` when interpreter is started in `dir/` will succeed.

Similarly for unit tests:
`python3 -m unittest discover --start-directory=.` successfully works from `dir/`, but not from `dir/package/`.